# How can tab's page reset to initial state when moving from one tab to another in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny, shinyjs

How can tab's page reset to initial state when moving from one tab to another in R shiny?That is consider that there are two tabs A abs B.When A is clicked and some actions are performed in A such as button click and filling a form and all.Then when moving to tab B and again to tab A.Then tab A should be reset to its initial state.Can this action be performed automatically when moving from one tab to another without clicking button  in R?

My code is

ui.R

shinyUI(
navbarMenu
    ( 
    "IDnavbarmenu",

```
tabPanel("A", fluidRow( column(2,
                          actionButton("button1", "button1")))),
tabPanel("B")
```

)
)

Server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

observeEvent(
    input$button1,

output$ui1 <- renderUI({isolate({

```
  div( id="g",
fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

          fluidRow(column(4, 
                textInput("name", label = "NAME:", 
                          value ='')))))})}))
```

}

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved. Look at the `reset` function in `shinyjs` package

Comment: Thank You,but where should this function be used?

Comment: Whenever you want to perform the reset.  It sounds like you want to reset when the tab is changed, so you have to figure out how to know when a tab is changed, which is simple enough if you look at documentation or examples online

Comment: I have checked many documents ,but in all of them the Tab gets reset on button click.But is it possible to reset tabs on moving from one tab to another in R shiny without button click?

Comment: As I said, yes; use the `shinyjs::reset()` function when a tab change happens. If you know how to reset on click, you can reset on tab change as well, you just need to put the same code from the click observer to an observer that runs when the tab changes. You can know when a tab is changed by attaching an observer to the tabPanel id, since it can act like a regular input, returning the value of the selected tab.  I can't write you the code for you, but it's not hard. Google for it if you don't understand how to do that